# Converting multiple related rows in a dataframe to a single row for Machine learning

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, machine-learning

I'm very new at python and ML. I need to be able to do classification type machine learning (SVM or KNN for example) on the following data (toy example):

```
dfRaw = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 6], [1, 3, 6], [2, 38, 80], [2, 45, 66], [3, 100, 120],[3, 90, 110], [3, 115, 125], [3, 99, 101]], columns=['Sample', 'A1', 'A2'])

   Sample   A1   A2
0       1    2    3
1       1    4    6
2       1    3    6
3       2   38   80
4       2   45   66
5       3  100  120
6       3   90  110
7       3  115  125
8       3   99, 101
```

But I think I need to create a dataframe where each 'Sample' is a single row like this:

```
dfFin = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 6], [2, 38, 80, 45, 66], [3,100,120,90,110,115,125,99,101]], columns=['Sample', 'A1', 'A2','B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'D1', 'D2' ]
print (dfFin)
   Sample   A1   A2  B1   B2     C1     C2    D1     D2
0       1    2    3   4    6    3.0    6.0   NaN    NaN
1       2   38   80  45   66    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
2       3  100  120  90  110  115.0  125.0  99.0  101.0
```

Questions:

1. Am I right in thinking I need to transform each 'Sample' into a single row
2. If so how to I iterate through a dataframe to do this transformation.
3. Note the data set will have differing numbers of features per 'Sample' can I still do classification on this irregular shape.
4. Note also that each pairing of A1,A2 or B1,B2 are related and relevant 
   Thanks

Comment: This is impossible to answer without some context. What is A1 and A2?

Comment: A1 and A2 are just 2 related readings and will always be numbers. eg. average temp and altitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.

Yes. Since most machine learning applications expect an input of shape `(samples, features)` you are correct to think that you need to transform each sample into a single row.

#### 2.

One way of doing it is by adding a new column that enumerates the multiple 'readings' for each `Sample`, then use a `pivot` to get them into rows.

```
# Add enumeration per sample using `comcount` on group
dfRaw['reading'] = dfRaw.groupby('Sample').cumcount()

# Pivot
dfFin = dfRaw.pivot(index='Sample', columns='reading')

# If desired: reduce multi-index header to single-index header
dfFin.columns = [''.join(str(col)).strip() for col in dfFin.columns.values]
dfFin.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

*Output:*

```
        ('A1', 0L)  ('A1', 1L)  ('A1', 2L)  ('A1', 3L)  ('A2', 0L)  \
Sample                                                               
1              2.0         4.0         3.0         NaN         3.0   
2             38.0        45.0         NaN         NaN        80.0   
3            100.0        90.0       115.0        99.0       120.0   

        ('A2', 1L)  ('A2', 2L)  ('A2', 3L)  
Sample                                      
1              6.0         6.0         NaN  
2             66.0         NaN         NaN  
3            110.0       125.0       101.0
```

In the resulting column names, `0L, 1L, ...` represent the 'readings' and `A1, A2` represent the two features per 'reading'. The column headers thus map to those those you used in your example output by `0L:A`, `1L:B`, `2L:C`, `3L:D` combined with `A1:1`, `A2:2`. It's a bit confusing but I don't have the atm to think of a simple and general automated way of renaming the columns to exactly match your example, especially since this is not really important here.

#### 3.

I don't know of any simple classifiers (`SVM` and such) that can properly deal with missing values.

You'll have to drop either all rows or all columns containing `NaN` values. Dropping columns (features) is more common, as dropping rows (samples) will mean that you won't be able to use your classifier later on to predict labels for any new samples that have `NaN` values.

If dropping `NaN` columns would mean a massive loss of data in your case and render the problem unsolvable, you may have to start thinking about a more complicated model for your data and use e.g. a `Bayesian` approach to fit it.

#### 4.

Since the column names still identify the 'reading' (`0L, 1L, ...`) as well as the original column names (`A1, A2`), the information about the pairings is retained in case you need it later on.